# Mixpanel nameTag not working iOS

Tags: ios, mixpanel

Basically I have used the following code to log an event in the mix panel.

```
         [mixpanel track:@"App Launched"];
         [mixpanel identify:[user objectForKey:@"email"]];
         mixpanel.nameTag =[user objectForKey:@"email"];
```

But the problem is that `Mixpanel stream` is showing `Guest#2324` instead of the emailID. I have confirmed that I am getting `[user objectForKey:@"email"]` value. Can anybody figure it out as where I am doing wrong. I have initialized the mix panel using

```
mixpanel = [Mixpanel sharedInstance];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be remove the `identify` line from the above code.As identify is used to identify the device.Refer [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/site_media/doctyl/uploads/iPhone-spec/Classes/Mixpanel/index.html) for more details.